# If I know that the rows of a database table are inserted sequentially, can I use this to speed up SELECT queries?

Tags: mysql

I'm populating some tables in a database to represent vector lines.

```
"INSERT INTO entities(drawing,eID,etype) VALUES(27,2566317,19);"
```

The etype '19' indicates that this is a polyline, so it will have multiple entries in the 'points' table:

```
"INSERT INTO points(drawing,eID,X,Y,Z) VALUES(27,2566317,40,500,0);"
"INSERT INTO points(drawing,eID,X,Y,Z) VALUES(27,2566317,50,500,0);"
"INSERT INTO points(drawing,eID,X,Y,Z) VALUES(27,2566317,50,600,0);"
"...."
```

Other tables contain information about colour, dashed line, line thickness, etc.

When I extract the data, I first step through the 'entities' table:

```
"SELECT eID,etype FROM entities WHERE drawing=27;"
```

Then, based on the entity type, I extract the information needed to render the entity.

```
"SELECT X,Y,Z FROM points WHERE drawing=27 and eID=2566317;"
"SELECT linethick FROM params WHERE drawing=27 AND eID=2566317;"
"SELECT flag FROM flags WHERE drawing=27 AND eID=2566317;"
```

My question is this: Does the database begin searching from the beginning of the 'points' table when I move on to the next entity? or does it start from where it left off?

I'm assuming it's the former, in which case, can I tell it to disregard the previous 'points' table entries and start the search from where it left off in the table?

On the same subject, if I know that drawing 27 occupies the rows in the 'entities'table  between 470,229 and 875,421, can I limit the search on that basis?

I'm using MariaDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table is scanned based on index, so if your `drawing` and `eID` is keys, then it directly knows where to look for it and skips full table scan.

If there is no proper keys, then it scans whole table to find what it's looking for and there is no guaranteed order (since you do not provide order clause).

---

To speed up search:

1. Use single query:

```sql
SELECT X, Y, Z, linethick, flag
FROM points pt
JOIN params pr ON pt.drawing = pr.drawing AND pt.eID = pr.eID
JOIN flags f ON pt.drawing = f.drawing AND f.eID = pr.eID
WHERE pt.drawing=:drawingID AND eID=:eID
```

2. Add proper indexes (e.g. FOREIGN KEY) on `drawing` and `eID`

Comment: Thanks. That is very helpful. Often, just the process of formulating a question can suggest search phrases and I have found that MariaDB has FETCH and OFFSET keywords to narrow down the range. I do have drawing and eID as keys of all tables and will look at FOREIGN KEY as you suggest. Lastly, thanks for the JOIN suggestion. I was a little concerned that duplicated values (if there are 10 points, then there be 10 identical line thicknesses in the returned rows) might carry their own overheads.

Comment: Just to be clear, if I know that a table is produced sequentially, there is no benefit in limiting a search to a range of rows commencing at a certain OFFSET because this is already accomplished by my 'drawing' index?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure, you have already indexed the columns used in where clause,if not , suggested to do so.

Mysql generally do the full table scan for a wherre clause depend upon the column, however, this can be figured out by

**EXPLAIN** and  **ANALYZE** keyword.

You can use **EXPLAIN** for the select query and **ANALYZE** for the table.

- output from EXPLAIN shows **ALL** in the type column when MySQL uses a
  full table scan to resolve a query.
- ANALYZE TABLE tbl_name to update the key distributions for the scanned table

REf: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/table-scan-avoidance.html